# Does “valeur” always translate “value”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire

I'm writing about *value* in the personal sense of the word, as in *emotional value*, *moral value* or *aesthetic value*.

I'm thinking that perhaps “*valeur*” refers mainly to monetary value and I was wondering if there was an alternative that was more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“*Valeur*” is by no means restrained to monetary value : asking the [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/valeur) (in French), only its 4<sup>th</sup> sense is that of price, coming after the *quality* of something, *nobility*, and *importance* (*interest*).

<sup>The 7<sup>th</sup> sense (a rule of one's ideology) is also probably of interest for you (your question made me think of it at first).</sup>

Answering more directly your question, the [English Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valeur) — aside from “value” — gives another sense to “*valeur*” : [“valor”](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valor), i.e. *bravery*, *courage*. Again, not so monetary.

- Is there an alternative ?

Interestingly, [the French Wiktionary for “value”](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/value#Anglais) first mentions **“*mérite*”**, before “*valeur*”.

Comment: Aha, French Wiktionary, I didn't think to look whether it existed. I've just been using the not very useful resources that one gets googling 'french dictionary'.

Comment: Yes, 1,3 and 7 are particularly relevant. 3 is perfect.